# VSCode Markdown with MathJax

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, mathjax

I take notes in Markdown, and I'd like to use VSCode as my primary editor, but I require MathJax support.  It doesn't have to render in the preview pane (although this would be ideal)- I would settle for a way of compiling down into HTML and having the MathJax expressions be evaluated by the browser.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, to compile your Markdown with MathJAX to HTML easily, you could do this with an extension. Otherwise just defer to external tools.

Comment: The documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown might be useful for building a simple workflow that adds a script tag for MathJax to markdown before compilation to HTML.

Comment: Try the extension [Markdown+Math](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=goessner.mdmath) of VSCode.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, Could you elaborate on that? How could one make the preview of VS Code to load MathJaX script on preview? Is there like a Default HTML file one could edit?

Answer (score 0):

I am using VSCode for creating github pages. I uses Jekyll as static generator. In this case its easy use LATEX in markdown, if you specify the mathjax CDN in your default.html. (Which is the template for creating html from markdown)

Comment: Could you exactly how? Thank You.